# Unable to display the language Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: language-pack, ubuntu-13.04

I have recently upgraded to `Ubuntu 13.04`. The main problem is as shown in the figure...!!!
[image]

I had a lot of pain in taking the screenshot. I started upgrading during the night, and left it to itself. I thought that it would ask a prompt for `Language Selection`. But i didn't see anything when I woke up.

But the fortunate thing is that the `tty`s are working fine. Also I am unable to see the bar on the top and left and hence I am unable to open a previously `minimised` application.

Please somebody help me overcome this issue.(`Other than reinstalling the entire thing`).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` should re-install the Unity desktop and all the packages needed, but my guess you are having an issue because English is not your default language(?). The bar on top and left are probably not showing because you have a graphics card driver being loaded on boot, did you install any graphics card drive previously before the upgrade?

Comment: English is my default language. and the command which you were saying didn't work(should I reboot the system?).`:(` I didn't install any graphic driver also.. btw it didn't download anything from the internet when I executed the command.